# golang: call C++ code in cross platform

Tags: c++, macos, go

Is there a way to call C++ code from Go ? I need to call C++ code in Windows and Mac. Does Go language support cross language integration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [SWIG and Go](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Go.html)
>
> Go is a compiled language, not a scripting language. However, it does
>   not support direct calling of functions written in C/C++. The cgo
>   program may be used to generate wrappers to call C code from Go, but
>   there is no convenient way to call C++ code. SWIG fills this gap.

Use SWIG.

Comment: If you want to avoid having to mess with SWIG you can write "extern C" functions that call the C++ functions you want to use, then you call call the C bridge functions using cgo: http://golang.org/cmd/cgo/